# How can <f:setPropertyActionListener> used with primefaces datatable rowExpansion

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable, rowexpansion

can `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` be used in primefaces datatable rowExpansion? I tried

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{queryStudiesBean.onRowToggle}" >
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{queryPatientBean.test}" value="sucess"/>
</p:ajax>
```

but it says

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource
```

also I tried

```
<p:rowToggler>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{queryPatientBean.test}" value="sucess"/>
</p:rowToggler>
```

but it gives the same error, is there anyway to use it?

Answer (score 1):

<f:setPropertyActionListener> works with ActionSource components like <p:commandLink> and <p:commandButton>.

```
<p:rowExpansion>
   <p:commandLink>
      <f:setPropertyActionListener>
   </p:commandLink>
</p:rowExpansion>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I knew how to do it finally, I put the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` inside remoteCommand, which in turn needs to be inside a form:

```
<form>
      <p:remoteCommand name="callButton" ajax="false" id="callButton" action="#{queryPatientBean.printTest()}">
           <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{queryPatientBean.test}" value="success"/>
      </p:remoteCommand>
</form>
```

then I called this remoteCommand from `<p:ajax> onstart`:

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" onstart="callButton();" listener="#{queryStudiesBean.onRowToggle}" />
```

Comment: This requires an additional Ajax request. It's better to just set success in the `onRowToggle` method.